# Rotate Object relative to other Object

Tags: rotations

I have an object (cube) which has two other objects attached to it (cones). If I rotate the cube along any axis, how do I determine the rotation of the cones (which emanate at a specific angle from the exact center of the cube) in relation to the cube's rotation?[image: rotation example]